# Rotating an image in canvas keeping to the top left

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to rotate an image inside a canvas but keeping the image to the top left. I have managed to get it to stay to the top left but only on the first and second rotation steps.

The rotation steps I would like are:

[image]

I would also like it to scale well depending on screen size which I have already done. Sorry for the short description but I have made a fiddle. As you can see the 3rd and 4th steps the image is taken off the canvas which is wrong.

[Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jNWT5/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/jNWT5/1/)

The area of the code that is performing the transform is:

```
function rotate() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cDimensions.width, cDimensions.height);

    ctx.translate(pasteH,0); 

    ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);

    pasteImage();

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a great write up on canvas rotating: http://codetheory.in/canvas-rotating-and-scaling-images-around-a-particular-point/. It might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're on the right track!**

- First translate to where you want the rotation point to be (in your case 0,0).  Since the default canvas rotation point is 0,0 this step is optional in your case.
- Next rotate the canvas through your 4 rotations: 0, PI/2, PI, PI*1.5.
- Finally drawImage with the appropriate offsets that you desire (in your case to pull the image over to 0,0)

[image][image]

[image][image]

Here's an array with the angle and offsets needed for your 4 rotations:

```
var rotations=[];
rotations.push({angle:0,offsetX:0,offsetY:0});
rotations.push({angle:PI/2,offsetX:0,offsetY:-img.height});
rotations.push({angle:PI,offsetX:-img.width,offsetY:-img.height});
rotations.push({angle:PI*1.5,offsetX:-img.width,offsetY:0});
```

Heres a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ryA8f/

Comment: Thanks - I need to brush up on my Maths!